# count the number of customers who ordered twice for each month

Tags: sql, mysql

i have table like this (each row represents an order):

```
order_id   date                    customer_id 
11        '2023-01-01 00:03:43'    123
12        '2023-02-01 00:02:43'    456
13        '2023-02-01 00:03:44'    789
14        '2023-04-01 00:03:43'    1230
```

i tried this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m') , COUNT(distinct customer_id) as count
FROM `order` o
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(o.date,'%Y-%m') 
HAVING COUNT(o.customer_id) > 1
```

It works but also counts customers from previous months. For example, a customer counted in January should not be counted in February. How can I do that ?

Comment: Do you need a count based on the months like `Jan, Feb ..` or do you need to count based on the current or fixed month?

Comment: hi @BhargavChudasama, i need all months.

Comment: Which version of mysql are you using ?

Comment: version is mysql 5.7.0

Answer (score 1):

try this query. Return the result of all distinct customer counts per month and year-wise.

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(o.date) AS year,
    MONTH(o.date) AS month,
    COUNT(distinct customer_id) AS count
FROM 
    order o
GROUP BY 
    YEAR(o.date),
    MONTH(o.date)
ORDER BY 
    YEAR(o.date) ASC,
    MONTH(o.date) ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

> It works but also counts customers from previous months. For example,
> a customer counted in January should not be counted in February. How
> can I do that ?

To ensure that each customer is counted just once, we will obtain the earliest date possible for each customer using `groub by` and `min()`:

```
select customer_id, min(date) as min_date
from mytable
group by customer_id
```

Then apply your logic using `group by` and `having` on this dataset :

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(min_date,'%Y-%m') , COUNT(customer_id) as count
FROM (
  select customer_id, min(date) as min_date
  from mytable
  group by customer_id
) o
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(o.min_date,'%Y-%m') 
HAVING COUNT(o.customer_id) > 1;
```

[Demo here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/j5MeMyCMvYtF3RcnjePP64/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can first find out which customers have more exactly two orders per month:

```
select customer_id, DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m') as 'month'
from `order` o
group by customer_id, DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m')
having count(*) = 2
```

Now that you have that list, you can calculate number of customers per month:

```
select `month`, count(customer_id) 'Customer_cnt'
from (
  select customer_id, DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m') as 'month'
  from `order` o
  group by customer_id, DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m')
  having count(*) = 2
) as q
group by `month`
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gnJG9dJMqY2boJCgiMqzFX/0)